# Null pointer exception of List View

Tags: android

I'm getting null pointer exception at list view. when list view created in the activity_main.xml it works fine, but when i create listview in a separate file error is occurred.

```
package pk.edu.pucit.lab_02;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] username = { "hamad", "ali", "ahmed", "riaz", "hamad", "ali",
                "ahmed", "riaz", "hamad", "ali", "ahmed", "riaz", "hamad",
                "ali", "ahmed", "riaz", "hamad", "ali", "ahmed", "riaz",
                "hamad", "ali", "ahmed", "riaz", "hamad", "ali", "ahmed",
                "riaz" };

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.acticity_linear_layout,
                R.id.names, username);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

this is my activity_linear_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my activity_list_view.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
</ListView>
```

this is my menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pk.edu.pucit.lab_02"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: paste logcat here and also the second case code which gives you exception.

Comment: You've only posted working code, and it does indeed look fine. Please post the part that doesn't work (the different-file part), and also the crash stack.

Comment: your `activity_main.xml`needs to include a ListView with ID listView. Don't put it in a seperate `activity_list_view.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But listView is part of `activity_list_view` so `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` will return null pointer.

fix it by moving `listView` inside of the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.listView` is no longer part of `R.layout.activity_main`

Which is not available here

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

but you search for here

`ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`

giving you null.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your main xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TextView>
 <include
        android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="..."
        android:layout_toLeftOf="..."
        layout="@layout/activity_list_view" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scores"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```